# are two results from a single key in dynmodbo counted as two I/O?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, key-value, nosql

We are migrating our MYSQL DB to DynamoDB. Issue with dynamoDb for our website is that we have a lot of I/O. dynamoDB's costs increases significantly due to high I/O. my question is best asked as an example:

Suppose I track the message for a user. suppose user id is Key. So we have a user Id 1. And the message number is the Range Key in incremental values. And we have three messages, 1,2,3. I will make a table for you

Key....Range.......Message
1.......1................UK Elects New PM
1.......2...............US Weather is cold
1.......3...............Google Funds

And suppose I do a query which says show messages with All Key=1, and Range >1. This will return 2 items. Message 2, and 3 will get returned.

Does dynamo DB count that as two I/O because two records were returned? Or does dynamoDB count that as one record because a query was run against one key.

Answer (score 0):

This would either count as 1 I/O or 2 I/O or even more because it depends on the size of your row.

The exact definition:
A unit of read capacity represents one strongly consistent read per second (or two eventually consistent reads per second) for items as large as 4 KB

So if your rows are very large (100 KB), and your query returns 2 of them, then it will be 100*2/4 = 50 I/O. The I/O here is the same unit as the one used in Provisioned Throughput.

The official doc is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughputIntro.html)